# Mutually exclusive Checkbox in Excel (Toggle)

Tags: excel, checkbox, toggle

I have spreadsheet with 50+ checkboxes from the forms toolbar. In a few instances you can only check 1 checkbox from a group i.e you check one checkbox from checkbox 1 to checkbox 5.

I'm trying to achieve this without any code if possible. Option button is not preferred since I want an uniformed spreadsheet.

How can you group the checkbox1 to checkbox5 so that they become mutually exclusive for a group.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a radio button, with possibly a separator between the groups, as this also signifies to the end-user that those fields are mutually exclusive.

A radio button, by definition, is Mutually Exclusive within a group.

Remember that using checkboxes in places where you should be using radio boxes will be confusing your end-users, as they wonder why that checkbox is suddenly de-activated, while when using radio buttons the confusion factor is non-existant.

Comment: I'm trying to find another way then using radio button because all the rest of my spreasheet has checkboxes. I want to keep the uniformity of my spreadsheet.

Comment: Communicating the behaviour of certain elements to your end-user is usually more important than this "uniformity" - remember, this uniformity can be reached by making your check and radio boxes all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use Option Buttons, try this code

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()

    With Me.CheckBox1
        If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Change()

    With Me.CheckBox2
        If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox3_Change()

    With Me.CheckBox3
        If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ClearGroup(sGroup As String, sName As String)

    Dim ole As OLEObject

    For Each ole In Me.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            If ole.Object.GroupName = sGroup And ole.Name <> sName Then
                ole.Object.Value = False
            End If
        End If
    Next ole

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think option (radio) buttons are mutually exclusive?   I have two of them in a group.  When I click one of them, the other turns on.  And there is no way to deselect them.  They initially worked as intended, but when I created a second group for an unrelated control with a different link box with two more option buttons, the bizarre behavior began.  So far, the best I can do is a separate radio button for each COMBINATION of controls and NO group.